# Extracting cookie using python3 + requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, http-headers

I am trying to extract the "cookie" value from request headers using requests.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
print(r.request.headers)
```

Analysing the request using Chrome Developer Tools, there is a cookie in the request headers, visible, however using the above code, it does not list that cookie.

It should be noted it is not listed using "r.cookies" either, returning "<RequestsCookieJar[]>".

Comment: Maybe the server reacts on the request headers, e. g. the user agent and decides if to send the cookie.

Comment: @MichaelButscher even with the same User-Agent passed in to the request, it is not gathering the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually depends on the website that you have requested. Some of the websites may be set the cookies with Javascript or other method so that's why the `requests` library won't be able to capture the `cookies` response and you can't seeing them in the `<RequestsCookieJar[]>` response.

But if you try request to the github.com for example, you can able to extract the cookie response with something like

```py
resp = requests.get("https://github.com") # not login as user
cookies = resp.cookies
for cookie in cookies:
    print(cookie.name, cookie.value)
```

you will be able to see the cookies response like this

```bash
_octo GH1.1.1697863533.1679888536
logged_in no
_gh_sess wRZmJBwnEL9NvQkySvh17qzlE%2F1owIzJoAI9vSy54SmPuxipr%2BSGxnqux9ZtnAPahyptRhqxGebDQtv6oc7%2BMMX3fjcgNbUnjgpGstRQvjkF78n%2F69PqSQmzQpHiCpig9vBQnEx3JOC3T%2Bw33ZzPP55TDQsK%2BVoY1KpGCTlwpyl%2BqQSSQ1h9amKxxlXb5emoDUbX90PJoWM3B6x4VE5oIaW2XjbxPCxvIZ2z1C9rUegbyFj8hl45o4ALdLosUF3gPaReEFEV2jaEvPWK1C8sVg%3D%3D--pagdfW8R9B2fmeUv--pBG6cOK8Yb0Sr3RB%2BwjyaQ%3D%3D
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Do you think you could provide a way to extract them?

Comment: you can iterate all over the cookies based on the cookies response with `cookie.name` or `cookie.value` but its depending on the website that you have requested, so it will be vary. If you need to access cookies from all the headers i think you need another library for that